# MYSQL select info from sum within the query

Tags: mysql

this query works but pulls all results. I would like it to only pull results that are not 0.00 which is the totaldue. This is calculated within the query but I do not know how to exclude results with 0.00?

```
SELECT name,
SUM(IF(timeperiod='0',totalinv-paidtotal,0)) AS p0030,
SUM(IF(timeperiod='30',totalinv-paidtotal,0)) AS p3060,
SUM(IF(timeperiod='60',totalinv-paidtotal,0)) AS p6090,
SUM(IF(timeperiod='90',totalinv-paidtotal,0)) AS p9000,
SUM(totalinv)-SUM(paidtotal) AS totaldue
FROM
(
    SELECT primary_key, name, timeperiod, totalinv, SUM(paidtotal) as paidtotal
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            a.primary_key,
            a_name AS name, 
            CAST(totalinv AS DECIMAL(10,2)) as totalinv,
            CAST(IFNULL(amount,0) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) as paidtotal,
            CASE
                WHEN invoicedate > DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE($today,'%Y%m%d'),INTERVAL 29 DAY) THEN '0'
                WHEN invoicedate > DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE($today,'%Y%m%d'),INTERVAL 59 DAY) AND invoicedate <= DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE($today,'%Y%m%d'),INTERVAL 29 DAY) THEN '30'
                WHEN invoicedate > DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE($today,'%Y%m%d'),INTERVAL 89 DAY) AND invoicedate <= DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE($today,'%Y%m%d'),INTERVAL 29 DAY) THEN '60'
                ELSE '90'
            END AS timeperiod
        FROM $mysql_billing a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN $mysql_billing_dates b ON a.primary_key = b.id
        WHERE $today >= invoicedate
        AND $totaldue!='0.00'
        AND void='' 
    ) foo
    GROUP BY primary_key, name, timeperiod
) bar
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Comment: What's with the `$totaldue`? Is it a PHP variable from outside this string? What column (within the table!) is related to totaldue?  Right now as long as this external variable is non-zero then all records will be returned and if this external variable is zero then no records will be returned.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm pretty sure this whole thing can be done without a single sub-query. Learn to use `JOIN` rather than sub-query - it's much more efficient performance-wise as well as being easier to read.

Comment: How can you select totalinv without any aggregate function and group by everything but that? What possible value can it give?!  I'm pretty sure it needs to be `SELECT primary_key, name, timeperiod, SUM(totalinv), ...`

Comment: the totaldue was my attempt at what I thought it should be. It was incorrect.

Comment: Performance is what I am having problems with so I thought to reduce that, I would not pull 0.00 results. I am getting timeout errors when running the query on the tables as they each have about 7000 records a piece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing a `HAVING` at the very end:

```
....
GROUP BY name
HAVING totaldue != 0
ORDER BY name ASC
```

That will allow you to select on your calculated/grouped column.

Comment: this did what I asked, thank you. I guess I will have to figure out how to make this so it doesn't timeout mysql